# Unable to declare point() type in Java15

Tags: primitive-types

```
3    import java.awt.*;
4    
5    public class Main {
6    
7        public static void main(String[] args) {
8            Point point1 = new Point(x:1, y:1);
9            Point point2 = point1;
10           point1.x = 2;
11           System.out.println(point2);
12       }
13   }
```

I'm getting an error that '`)`', '`;`' is expected in *line 8* and *line 8* is not a statement. (Currently using Java15)

Answer (score 0):

Below fixed the issue for me

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
        Point point1 = new Point(1, 1);
        Point point2 = point1;
        point1.x = 2;
    System.out.println(point2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can "cancel" post edits. When clicking `edit` below a post, you get to see the "markdown" "source text" for the post and have a look at, say, *how* they got some program source code presented as a *code block*. Or, if such shows, click `edited…ago` and have a look at the revision history and changes. Then, there is always [The Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code).